# Understanding the SOCKS5 protocol RFC

Tags: tcp, network-protocols, socks

I am reading the SOCKS5 [RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt), it has:

> CONNECT
>
> In the reply to a CONNECT, BND.PORT contains the port number that the
>      server assigned to connect to the target host, while BND.ADDR
>      contains the associated IP address.  The supplied BND.ADDR is often
>      different from the IP address that the client uses to reach the SOCKS
>      server, **since such servers are often multi-homed.  It is expected
>      that the SOCKS server will use DST.ADDR and DST.PORT, and the
>      client-side source address and port in evaluating the CONNECT
>      request**.

For the last part of this paragraph, I have two questions:

1. The doc states that SOCKS servers are often multi-homed, and will reply to the client different bound address and port than the ones the client originally connects to. Does this mean the SOCKS server the client connects to redirects the connection to another SOCKS server? If so, what is point of letting the client sense the presence of the redirected SOCKS server? What will a client normally do with the bound address and port the SOCKS server replies?
2. The doc states *It is expected that the SOCKS server will use DST.ADDR and DST.PORT, and the client-side source address and port in evaluating the CONNECT request*, what exactly does it mean by **evaluating** the CONNECT request? What am I supposed to do in this **evaluating** process if I am implementing a SOCKS server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No. It means the server has 2 (or more) network cards/connections -- you communicate with the server on cardA, but when that server connects to the device downstream, it uses cardB.
2. That's up to you really...perhaps you want to blacklist/whitelist certain clients/servers/ports (ex. only allow clients from your country, or only allow connections to a specific country). Good example is not letting a client connect back to itself (?). Just a guess. Usually RFCs are good about saying "MUST, MIGHT, MUST NOT, etc" ..if it says "expected", to me that sounds like  'might' which basically means 'can, but doesn't have to.'

Answer (score 3):

1. SOCKS proxies are multi-homed because they are often installed at network boundaries like firewalls. The client connects to the internal interface of the firewall but the outgoing address is the external face. Since some protocols like FTP need to include the external visible IP address and port in-band (see FTP data transfer, i.e. PORT and PASV) they need to know this externally visible IP and port.
2. A normal socks proxy will connect where the clients wants to, i.e. DST. But when an upstream proxy is configured or when firewall ACL say different the proxy might behave differently.